# How to batch audio data for TTS model training

Tags: pytorch, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech, python-3.8

I am currently trying to implement the AdaSpeech TTS model proposed in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2103.00993) using pytorch, for which I need to create batches of data from a dataset to train the model.

The problem I have is that in order to create a tensor for a batch of data, the sequence length of the data must be the same, but audio data (converted to mel spectrogram frames) have different sequence lengths (audio length or number of frames).

I have tried reading through the papers on the base TTS model AdaSpeech is based on ([FastSpeech](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1905.09263) and [FastSpeech 2](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2006.04558)), but I can't seem to find the way they chose to batch sentences, only finding that they chose a batch size of 64. I have also tried to look at open source implementations of these models on github, but I couldn't understand how they did it either.

I have considered choosing an arbitrary sequence length and trimming the audio data; however, in order to train a TTS model, the audio transcript must be used as well, and this seems to make simply trimming the data undesirable as parts of a word may be cut off and create artifacts during inference.

Is there a way to make pytorch accept a batch of data with different sequence lengths? Is there a good way to batch audio data while avoiding lowering of model quality? Or is this just a compromise between training speed and resulting quality.

Here is the problem I ran into trying to create a batch with different sequence lengths:

Assuming a and b are blocks of data of length 2 and 3 respectively, trying to put them into a single tensor representing a batch of data produces a RuntimeError.

```
>>> a = torch.tensor([[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
>>> b = torch.tensor([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
>>> a=a.unsqueeze(0)
>>> b=b.unsqueeze(0)
>>> a
tensor([[[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]]])
>>> b
tensor([[[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]]])
>>> torch.cat((a,b))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 0. Expected size 2 but got size 3 for tensor number 1 in the list.
```

Answer (score 0):

tldr: sort data by sequence length and pad data to the same length according to batch size.

Alright, it seems like this isn't a popular enough topic for a quick answer, so I will post my temporary solution to this problem in case nobody ever feels like answering this question.

I have tried more research online, but it seems there is not a definitive answer to this very specific situation. However, I have found a not ideal but usable workaround.

It seems there are no way to batch data of different lengths and pack it into a single tensor for pytorch. So the only way to create batches for audio data (and its transcripts) is to pad the data to make batches. However, this could cause problems as there may end up being a lot of empty frames of audio data in a batch where one of the audio samples is really long. To minimize padding, first sort the audio samples by length.

After the audio samples are sorted by length, pad the audio files to match the longest audio sample in the batch, and then convert it to a tensor (say batch size is 4, pad the 3 shorter audio samples to match the longest 1).

As for the synchronization of the transcript data to the audio data, a special token (say "pad") can be used to represent the padding section of the audio data.

By using this method, the length of the audio samples can be matched, making batching the data possible, but this also causes a problem for batching. Since having extra padding in the training data will cause problems for learning, and making the batch size too big will lead to the need of putting in more padding in the shorter audio files, increasing batch size will decrease model quality. Since increasing batch size is a common way of increasing training speed, using this padding method leads to there being a trade off between training speed and model quality, requiring slower training speed for higher quality models.

Since I'm not an expert on this subject, I won't mark my own answer correct. I hope somebody with more expertise will come along and provide more information, in case somebody else runs into this problem in the future. :D